# start neo4j server in a specific folder?

Tags: neo4j

I am coming from the MongoDB world where I can start a mongo server in a specific folder :

```
$ mongod --dbpath ./myFolder
```

How do I do the same thing with Neo4j ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `conf/neo4j-server.properties` there's the setting you're looking for:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
```

Comment: So you could write a small script that just patches the properties file and then starts Neo with that config.